# EPUB preview libraries

Tags: php, javascript, epub

I´m working on an online bookstore that sells DRM free ebooks in epub format. Are there any libraries in php or js that´ll help me in the process of building a preview component (maybe the first 10 pages) that you know of?

so far I have found this:

Epubjs:
http://blog.threepress.org/2009/02/09/introducing-epubjs/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

epubs are just zipped HTML files, so extracting the first HTML file is pretty easy.

Except of course, you sell DRM'd files. If you finished implementing all the decryption stuff, tell us.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary/ does a good job of importing epub files with spine info and one of the examples will let you upload an epub which it later renders.

This is not in a page format though, so you would have to put the limit yourself.